# How do I implement a synchronous reset switch to my D-Flip Flop

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, logic-gates

This is my master slave D Flip Flop and I was wondering where do I put the reset switch to make it into a D Flip Flop positive edge with a synchronous switch. I know that for synchronous, you can reset only if you find yourself on the positive clock edge.

[image]

Comment: D flip-flops aren't really made with synchronous preset and clear signals, since those can be combined into the D signal really easily (OR with preset, AND with NOT reset).   Asynchronous clear is much more interesting

Answer (score 0):

The effect of a synchronous reset is the same as a low input on D. So you can simply AND the D input with an appropriate gate.

If your RESET input is active low, a simple 2-input AND is sufficient.

If your RESET input is active high, you invert it before the AND.

Since you already have an AND gate driven by D, you can extend it to a 3-input AND.